# Determine index number for inline shape

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to refer to an inline shape that I added in the middle of the document.  My current workaround is short term, and I'd like to solicit advice for a better solution.

The situation is I am adding an inline shape using .addpicture about half way through the document.  The issue with doing this is if there are inlineshapes after the location where I am inserting the picture, the index number for the inline shape I add isn't simply the nth shape added to the document.  Inlineshapes.count will not refer to the picture I just added, it refers to the picture at the end of the document.

My current workaround is to physically look at the document, count the number of shapes below where I am entering the new picture, and I can refer to it with something like inlineshapes(totalShapes-shapesBelow).select

The reason I'd like to do this is so I can crop the image area or perform other manipulation of the inlineshape, if necessary.

Comment: Are you wanting to edit the picture as soon as you have inserted it? Or at a later stage go back using script to then edit the picture?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen The plan was to come back to it later, but your question of asking if I wanted to edit it as soon as I insert the picture just changed my mind!  Makes way more sense to do it that way.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I'm understanding you correctly the correct way to "get a handle" on the thing you're inserting so that you can continue working with it is to assign it to an object variable at the same time it's created, then work with that:

```
Dim ils as Word.InlineShape
Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture('parameters here)
ils.Width = 100
```

If you really want the index value, then something like this:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Dim ils as Word.InlineShape
Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture('parameters here)
Set rng = ils.Range
rng.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.Start
Debug.Print rng.InlineShapes.Count
```

EDIT: Approach chosen by OP

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Dim bk As Word.Bookmark
Dim ils as Word.InlineShape
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
Set bk= ActiveDocument.Bookmarks([name])
rng.End = bk.Range.End
Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(bk.Range, other param)
Debug.Print rng.InlineShapes.Count
```

Comment: Cindy, thank you very much.  The code you provided doesn't do exactly what I need to do, but that is due to a poor explanation on my part.  It definitely led me on the correct path by using a range.  What I ended up doing is creating a range starting at the beginning of the document, the end of the range is just prior to the bookmark where I insert my image, and then I can use range.inlineshapes.count to find out the number of shapes in the document prior to the insertion point.  Unfortunately, I cannot post any code because the VBA code is at work and I cannot open up this website there.